# PDF and EPS export from ggplot2 results in white lines across density plot? help to remove?

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I keep getting these white lines after exporting to PDF. They aren't visible in R but appear visible once exported. This also seems to be a mac specific issue. Problem doesn't occur when exporting to tiff.

data:

```
> dput(head(newdemodf1,10))
structure(list(x = c(21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L), y = c(27L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 34L, 35L, 
36L), totaltime = c(0.0499999523162842, 0.0499999523162842, 0.379999876022339, 
0.0500004291534424, 0.0299999713897705, 0.109999895095825, 0.0499999523162842, 
0.0299999713897705, 0.0500001907348633, 0.0299999713897705)), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "totaltime"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

ggplot(newdemodf1) +
  stat_density2d(aes(x=x, y=y, z=totaltime, fill = ..density..), 
                 geom="tile", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=cols)
```

I then export to PDF to import into adobe illustrator. However, I get a plot like :

[image]

how do I remove the white lines? does this involve smoothing the colours? or changing the tiles in some way? missing x,y combinations? any help appreciated.

Comment: for removing grid / background from ggplot, see [link](http://felixfan.github.io/rstudy/2013/11/27/ggplot2-remove-grid-background-margin/)

Comment: hi, removing the ggplot2 grid doesn't help. it improves the look within R but export still results in the white lines. I used RStudio Export to PDF.

Comment: @agstudy how do you do your export?

Comment: When I run the code above, I get the error "Error in ggplot(newdemodf1) : object 'newdemodf1' not found".  Can you add the definition of newdemodf1.

Comment: We really need to see a `dput` of or a link to the data in `newdemodf1`.

Answer (score 6):

those white lines are typically artefacts of the pdf viewer you're using; they probably seem to move when you zoom in or out.

You can try "raster" instead of "tile", it seems to work better with Illustrator.

[image]

```
set.seed(4393)
dsmall <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
g1 <- ggplot(dsmall, aes(carat, price)) +
  stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE) 

g2 <- ggplot(dsmall, aes(carat, price)) +
  stat_density2d(geom="raster", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE) 

ggsave("g1.pdf",g1)
ggsave("g2.pdf",g2)
```

Comment: alternatively, select those tiles, and use `Effect>Rasterize` in Illustrator.